# Ember.js: How to get access to store from App object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Since Ember.Data 1.0 Beta we have to use store.find('model') instead App.Model.find(). How to get access to store object inside App object?

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  auth: function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // ... get token somehow ...
      // how to get store?
      this.store.find('user').then(function(users) {
        App.set('user', users.get('firstObject');
        resolve();
      }, function(err) {
        reject();  
      });
    });
  }
});

App.deferReadiness();
App.auth().then(App.advanceReadiness());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an initializer that injects the store into the application object.

```
App.initializer({
    name: 'Inject Store',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        container.injection('application:main', 'store', 'store:main');
    }
});
```

Afterwards you can use `this.get('store')` in the application. Of course you can circumvent the container by simply setting the store (retrieved via `container.lookUp`) on the application object, but that defeats the purpose of the container.

Answer (score 5):

I've used this get the store in my main App object.  It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

```
var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main')
```

Comment: The app container is not intended to be used publicly. See [this post](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/5becdc4467573f80a5c5dbb51d97c6b9239714a8) from Yehuda Katz regarding this issue. You should inject the store as per the previous answer.